# Normalize 3d histogram so the sum under the curve = 1 in Matlab

Tags: matlab, 3d, histogram2d

I need to understand how can I make the 3d histogram of a data I have normalized, so the area under =1. 
I have

```
data=[data_x,data_y];
[HIST,Cent]=hist3(data];
```

I have read the post in :

[MatLab: Create 3D Histogram from sampled data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23907929/matlab-create-3d-histogram-from-sampled-data/23991496?s=2%7C1.4432#23991496)

But stil I cant understand the method. Can any expert help in explaining how to do it in Matlab?

Edit:

I have used the following code :

```
load('of.mat')
data=[single(theta(:)),mag(:)];
%define the x and y axis
edges{1} = -180:90:180;
edges{2} = 0:0.2:1;
hist3(data, 'Edges',edges);
[N,C]  = hist3(data, 'Edges',edges);
x_diff = diff(edges{1});
y_diff = diff(edges{2});
x = repmat([x_diff, x_diff(end)], length(edges{2}),1)';
y = repmat([y_diff, y_diff(end)], length(edges{1}),1);
% volume of the histogram
V_tot  = sum(sum(x.*y.*N));
N_norm = N/V_tot;
figure
% plot normalized histogram
bar3(-C{2}, N_norm');
axis normal
```

It works well, but how can I change the axis tics on the normalized histogram, its negative and my data should be positive. My data_x is between -180 and 180 (angle) and data_y is between 0 and 1. I can't post the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, if the bins are placed equally, this might give you a satisfactory result.

```
data = mvnrnd([0, 0], eye(2), 10e4);

%define the x and y axis
edges{1} = -4:0.5:4;
edges{2} = -4:0.2:4;

hist3(data, 'Edges', edges);

[N,C]  = hist3(data, 'Edges', edges);

x_diff = diff(edges{1});
y_diff = diff(edges{2});
x = repmat([x_diff, x_diff(end)], length(edges{2}),1)';
y = repmat([y_diff, y_diff(end)], length(edges{1}),1);

% volume of the histogram
V_tot  = sum(sum(x.*y.*N));

N_norm = N/V_tot;

figure
% plot normalized histogram
bar3(-C{2}, N_norm');
axis normal
```

Note that the bar3 plot requires some post-processing: changing the ticks of the axis and maybe the gap between and color of the bars.
I cannot post image so you should try to run the code and check whether the result is acceptable.

**EDIT:** Or you can modify the tick labels on the histogram's z axis using `V_tot`.

**EDIT:** Changing the tick labels of z axis (no bar3 plot):

```
data = mvnrnd([0, 0], eye(2), 10e4);

%define the x and y axis
edges{1} = -4:0.5:4;
edges{2} = -4:0.2:4;

hist3(data, 'Edges', edges);

[N,C]  = hist3(data, 'Edges', edges);

x_diff = diff(edges{1});
y_diff = diff(edges{2});
x = repmat([x_diff, x_diff(end)], length(edges{2}),1)';
y = repmat([y_diff, y_diff(end)], length(edges{1}),1);

% volume of the histogram
V_tot  = sum(sum(x.*y.*N));

% change the Z tick labels
z_tval = get(gca, 'ZTick');
z_norm_tval = z_tval/V_tot;
set(gca, 'ZTickLabel', z_norm_tval)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have edited the question according to you code. How to change the tics using V_tot?

Comment: @KaMu I extended my answer regarding how to change the tick labels. Hope this helps. It is not clear to me how you get negative values, without your data (of.mat) it hard to figure out. Maybe you can upload an image to an external site and post a link.

Comment: @KaMu If you think that my answer is solved your problem please accept it and the next time I will be able to post image as well. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much, I am still investigating why I am getting negative, I will post the image soon. Meanwhile, can you tell me what does this code part actually do? x = repmat([x_diff, x_diff(end)], length(edges{2}),1)';
y = repmat([y_diff, y_diff(end)], length(edges{1}),1);

Comment: The `repmat` function replicates the distance vector (`x_diff` and `y_diff`). The distance here means the distance between adjacent ticks; the number of replications equals to the number of ticks on the other (perpendicular) axis.  Basically `x` and `y` matrices contain the dimensions of every bin (rectangles) per x and y axes respectively, therefore, `x.*y` matrix shows the area of the bins (rectangles). I you have equally spaced ticks all elements of `x` and `y` would be the same.

Comment: Thanks for your time to post and reply for my questions. This totally solved my problem :).